# How to set value in Hidden form field using ngModel?

Tags: angular5

I'm sending value with hidden form field but value not set with [value] property of input tag.

Here is my code :

```
<input type="hidden" [(ngModel)]="model.tokenval" formControlName="hiddentoken" [value]="{{tokenval}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not set value like this.

You have to use setValue() and patchValue() methods of reactive form groups.

In setValue() you have to set all formGroup values and in patchValue() you can specify values which you want.

Reference Link: https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-formgroup-example#set-get